# How to find a javascript redirection in my website

Tags: javascript, code-injection, redirect

I have an injection on my website. When javascript is enabled the website redirects to another one.

How can I find out where the injection is?

Comment: javascript can be written in a number of ways, don't expect to find a plain crude redirect, it may be obfuscated, can you give an url to your site ?

Comment: Give us the URL please.

Answer (score 2):

1. Disable Javascript
2. Look at page source
3. Search for redirects

Another thing is that redirect can ge added to the site using Javascript. Maybe some content that you load using Javascript which won't be visible with Javascript disabled.

P.S. Quickest way I think would be by searching for the website you get redirected to in the page source.

Comment: I did this before, but nothing was founded !

Comment: [@MarcCostello](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18653589/2657216) makes a good point. Take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot find any javascript redirects in your code check for any and all ajax requests. A script maybe injected asynchronously